# Angular Module with no components

Tags: angular

In the Angular documentation for modules the example module consists of a template, a component, and a provider. The module is imported into the root module and instantiated by including the element defined by the component like so

```
<app-contact></app-contact>
```

I am creating a module that doesn't interact with the DOM at all. It is just a provider that makes http requests and stores the results. What is the proper way for other modules to import this module and have access to it's base class?

Comment: So you don't need any `declarations` and will have only the service in the `exports`? That seems fine. Did you try anything? What happened?

Comment: I can access the oauth class if import it directly, and inject it into another component, but what then is the point of the angular module decorator?

Comment: It allows you to define the dependencies of your service; it will still have `imports: [HttpModule]`, so even if it's being imported into a single project that isn't otherwise using that module it will still work.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks @jonrsharpe

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am reading the angular2 module documentation and this gotcha is provided https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#why-_userservice_-isn-t-shared . I am thinking that this applies to my case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's [a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html).  Services typically don't associate themselves with a view, but is code that can be used to *support* a view, such as retrieve documents and information from elsewhere via AJAX.  The tutorial I've linked above makes mention and example of these constructs.